# record all registry keys read/written by a process

Tags: windows, registry

How can I "record" which registry keys are accessed by a process?  Can I use process explorer or a similar tool to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645)